# How to reference an exception class in Python?

Tags: python, exception, namespaces, python-import, gpx

I want to catch a [GPSException](https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy/blob/master/gpxpy/gpx.py#L64) thrown by the [gpxpy library](https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy).

```
try:
    gpx = gpxpy.parse(open(filepath))
except GPXException:
    print "GPXException for %s." % filepath
```

Since I am new to Python I do not understand how one would reference the exception via namespace such as `gpxpy.gpx.GPSException` or an import statement such as ..

```
import gpxpy
import gpxpy.gpx
import gpxpy.gpx.GPSException
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to reference the exception correctly.

Either import the exception directly into your module, or use the full reference:

```
import gpxpy.gpx

try:
    # ...
except gpxpy.gpx.GPSException:
    # ...
```

or

```
from gpxpy.gpx import GPSException

try:
    # ...
except GPSException:
    # ...
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to using one method over the other?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro: ['import module' vs. 'from module import function'](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/187403)