# python skip importing a library

Tags: python, python-import

What I'd like to do is avoid an import that cause a problem. My code is like this:

main.py

```
import external_library
```

external_library.py

```
import package_with_problem
```

I know I could change `external_library.py` with something as

```
try:
    import package_with_problem
except:
    pass
```

but I'm looking for a solution to implement in `main.py`. I would like a skip function that takes the package name as parameters and avoid the import.

Comment: What have you tried so far, what what about what you tried doesn't work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131217/error-handling-when-importing-modules

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny yes, I can’t modify external_library. I could rewrite it ofc but it’s not a good solution imo. The “problem” is that in this library many packages are installed and used in functions that I don’t care about. One of this packages throws an error, but, in general, I don’t like importing a package that I don’t need (need to save space, time)

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I’m reading importlib documentation without any success

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40198924/handling-imported-module-exceptions

Comment: @AndrewRyan I don't want to throw an exception, I want to skip the import if the package name is "package_with_problem".

Answer (score 1):

Just do in `main.py` the same as you would have in `external_library.py`. If you only want to skip a certain import, you can check the error:

```py
try:
    import external_library
except ImportError as e:
    if "package_with_problem" not in e.msg:
        raise
```

This will "skip" the import of `package_with_problem` but will re-raise the error for any other package.

Comment: But in this way the external_library is not imported at all. This only avoid raising the error message

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, I believe it exists a better way to do this but anyway, this is my possible solution for now.

Create a new empty file.

new_empty_file.py

```
# nothing or print("Hello") to see something in output
```

main.py

```
import new_empty_file
import sys
sys.modules['package_with_problem'] = new_empty_file
import external_library # this should use package_with_problem in cache that is new_empty_file
```

If the import in external library has some subpackage, create a new function called as subpackage in new_empty_file as:

new_empty_file.py

```
def subpackage():
    return
```

Unfortunately, it is necessary to have `package_with_problem` in sys and installed, so, not a good solution, it only avoid importing the real library.